# If $p,q$ are prime numbers prove that $p=q^2+q+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers such that $p|q^3-1$ and $q|p-1$ then:

a) $p|(q^2+q+1)$
b) $p=q^2+q+1$

It is easy to prove part a but I am having troubles with part b. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: $(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: I used that to prove part a). How does it fit into part b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$q\mid p-1$ so $p=aq+1$
$p\mid q^2+q+1$ so $(aq+1)(bq+r)=q^2+q+1$ for some $r\in\{1,2,...,q-1\}$.
It is easy to see that $r=1$.  If $a$ and $b$ are both positive then $(aq+1)(bq+1)>q^2+q+1$

Comment: Thanks. I was trying something similar (to find an upper bound - the highest multiple of $p$ which was smaller than $q^2+q+1$)but I didn't express the number as $bq+r$ which is clearly very helpful.